# Recursive function with objects?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm writing a recursive method with classes. I'm not getting the output that I want at all.

```
public Result foo( cell, Result R )
{
    grid = createGrid( cell )
    if (grid.empty )
        return;
    else
    {
        // find best 2 cell.
        best_cells[] = findBestCell( grid );

        // saves best R found so far.
        R = updateResult( R );

        // call foo( best_cells[] );
        for ( every cell in best_cells[] )
            return foo( best_cells[i], R );
    }
    return R;
}
```

The method termites when the condition `if(grid.empty)` is `true` in the first time. It does not go for the other cells! Why is that? Am I missing a return?

Update 1:
Thanks Thomas for the notes. I changed the code to:

```
public Result foo( cell, Result R )
{
    grid = createGrid( cell )
    if (grid.empty )
        return R;
    else
    {
        // find best 2 cell.
        best_cells[] = findBestCell( grid );

        // saves best R found so far.
        R = updateResult( R );

        // call foo( best_cells[] );
        for ( every cell in best_cells[] )
        {
            Result temp_R = foo( best_cells[i], R );
            if( temp_R.error < R.error )
                R = temp_R;
            }

    }
    return R;
}
```

I'll test it then get back to u guys.

Update 2: The previous code works just fine now. The first input R must not be == null. Otherwise an NPE will appear.

Thanks Thomas so much! Thanks guys for ur comments :)

Comment: The first return should return some object of type `Result`.

Comment: What is this code? Please provide real compilable java code.

Comment: If that is the case then maybe your createGrid does not do what you expect it do.  Please examine it.

Comment: The compiler might attack you if you try to compile this code

Comment: @npinti The same incorrect output appears when it returns R.

Comment: @whoAmI Sorry I cannot give any more details about the code.

Comment: @user2310289 Other functions are all correct and return exactly what I want.

Comment: Asking non-compilation related question on un-compiled code has no meaning. If you want to ask why can't your code compile its a different thing. In that case please provide your code with the exact error you get.

Comment: Could you please check your second pseudo code? There seems to be a missing curly brace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without some more information and compilable code, it's hard to tell where your error is.
But here a few hints:

```
if (grid.empty )
    return;
```

What should be returned here? The `R` passed as a parameter?

```
for ( every cell in best_cells[] )
   return foo( best_cells[i], R );
```

This would stop after the first iteration (`best_cells[1]` and higher would never be examined). I guess you'd want to check the result of `foo( best_cells[i], R )` in some way and then decide whether to return it or continue iteration.

As a general note: if you ask us to look for errors in your code (and not just examine some algorithm) you should post that code instead of some pseudo code. Otherwise it's almost impossible to spot any *actual* error.

Another note: do you know how to use a debugger? If so, fire one up an check what your code does and what you'd expect it to do. Most likely you'll very quickly find the part where it goes wrong.

Comment: Now i'm getting null in Result :(!

Comment: @user2720596 well, what does your debugger tell you? As I said, without actual code it is nearly impossible to help any further than providing a few hints.